# Open Ionic2 App from Slider

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am trying out `Ionic 2` and am stuck with something. I have created a default side-menu app from CLI and added a `slider`. From my last slide, on button click/or from anchor link I would like to start my actual side-menu app.

**My app.ts**:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html'
})
class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = Slider;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>

  constructor(private platform: Platform) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Start', component: StartPage },
      { title: 'Farms', component: FarmList }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

**My slider.ts:**

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/slider/slider.html'
})
export class Slider {
    mySlideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    loop: true,
    pager: true
  };

  @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: Slides;

  goToSlide() {
    this.slider.slideTo(2, 500);
  }
}
```

**My slider.html:**

```
<ion-slides #mySlider [options]="mySlideOptions">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <button>Start</button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

As far as this default app as created from CLI I can see, it is not using routing fuction of `Angular2`. Is routing not needed in `Ionic2`, it handles in it's own way?

How can I start my actual app (i.e. 'start' page maybe) from slider?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `slider.html`

```
<ion-slides #mySlider [options]="mySlideOptions">
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 1</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 2</h1>
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Slide 3</h1>
    <!-- Added the click event handler -->
    <button (click)="goToHome()">Start</button>
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

And then in your `slider.ts`:

```
// Remember to import both the NavController and your StartPage

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/slider/slider.html'
})
export class Slider {

   constructor(nav: NavController){
       this.nav = nav;
   }

    mySlideOptions = {
    initialSlide: 0,
    loop: true,
    pager: true
  };

  @ViewChild('mySlider') slider: Slides;

  goToSlide() {
    this.slider.slideTo(2, 500);
  }

  // Added the method to handle the click
  goToHome(){
    this.nav.setRoot(StartPage );
  }
}
```

By adding the `(click="goToHome()")` in your view, and adding that method in your `component`, you should be able to start the app when clicking in that button from the slide.